# ng-click for ionic ios is not working

Tags: ios, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am creating mobile app using **ionic** framework in that I am going to implement facebook login.

My `fblogin()` function should called on `ng-click` but it didn't. Any help would be appreciated

```
<ion-view class="welcome-view" ng-controller="WelcomeCtrl as ctrl" cache-view="false"> 
  <ion-content scroll="false">
    <div class="top-content row">
      <div class="app-copy col col-top">
        <h1 class="app-logo">logo</h1>
        <p class="app-tagline">
            This app helps you discover and buy amazing things all in one place.
          </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom-content row">
      <div class="col col-bottom">
        <a class="facebook-sign-in button button-block" ng-click="facebookSignIn()">
          Log in with Facebook
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

my fblogin function

```
.controller('WelcomeCtrl', function($scope, $state, $q, UserService, $ionicLoading) {

            alert('Facebook login init');
 //This method is executed when the user press the "Login with facebook" button
  $scope.facebookSignIn = function() {

      alert('Facebook login init');
    facebookConnectPlugin.getLoginStatus(function(success){


     if(success.status === 'connected'){
        // the user is logged in and has authenticated your app, and response.authResponse supplies
        // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed request, and the time the access token
        // and signed request each expire
        console.log('getLoginStatus', success.status);

                //check if we have our user saved
                var user = UserService.getUser('facebook');

                if(!user.userID)
                {
                    getFacebookProfileInfo(success.authResponse)
                    .then(function(profileInfo) {

                        //for the purpose of this example I will store user data on local storage
                        UserService.setUser({
                            authResponse: success.authResponse,
                            userID: profileInfo.id,
                            name: profileInfo.name,
                            email: profileInfo.email,
                            picture : "http://graph.facebook.com/" + success.authResponse.userID + "/picture?type=large"
                        });

                        $state.go('app.home');

                    }, function(fail){
                        //fail get profile info
                        console.log('profile info fail', fail);
                    });
                }else{
                    $state.go('app.home');
                }

     } else {
        //if (success.status === 'not_authorized') the user is logged in to Facebook, but has not authenticated your app
        //else The person is not logged into Facebook, so we're not sure if they are logged into this app or not.
        console.log('getLoginStatus', success.status);

              $ionicLoading.show({
          template: 'Logging in...'
        });

        //ask the permissions you need. You can learn more about FB permissions here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.4
        facebookConnectPlugin.login(['email', 'public_profile'], fbLoginSuccess, fbLoginError);
      }
    });
  };

})
```

Comment: Can you put here your javascript function() in the controller and verify your javascript code is reachable from this page.

Comment: alert('Facebook login init');  This alert is called when app loads

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added in ionic play. Its working , Check here.

http://play.ionic.io/app/29b9296b6f89

Comment: can you check my fblogin function once?

Comment: where is ''WelcomeCtrl' defined in html. I meant ng-controller

Comment: <ion-view class="welcome-view" ng-controller="WelcomeCtrl as ctrl" cache-view="false">

Comment: Put ng-controller in body tag , like this     <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="mainController">

Comment: Remove ng-controller from <ion-view>

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your `ion-view` replace **TheNameOFController**  with the name of the controller you are using

```
ng-controller="TheNameOFController as ctrl"
```

and this to your `ng-click`

```
ng-click="ctrl.facebookSignIn()"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution for that

```
$scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function() {  

       $('*[ng-click]').each(function() {
            $(this).attr("ng-click");
            $(this).attr("on-touch", $(this).attr("ng-click"));
        });
});
```